# Android. Unresolved reference: repeatOnLifecycle

Tags: android, proguard, androidx, kotlin-flow, android-ktx

When I try to build release apk I get error:

> Unresolved reference: repeatOnLifecycle

When I build debug apk repeatOnLifecycle is resolved.

Why can this happen in the release version?

Note: in the release build, I additionally have the following setting:

```
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
```

Is it possible that this is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Faced with the same problem. Updating from `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1` to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0` helped me